# Second call to tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate finished after 1 step of training

Tags: tensorflow-estimator

I am running two tensorflow models using the tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate function one after the other.

```
# The first
train_spec = tf.estimator.TrainSpec(input_fn=my_input_fn("train"), max_steps=max_steps)
eval_spec = tf.estimator.EvalSpec(input_fn=my_input_fn("valid"), steps=None)
tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(model1, train_spec, eval_spec)

# the second
hook = [tf.estimator.StopAtStepHook(num_steps=max_steps)]
train_spec = tf.estimator.TrainSpec(input_fn=my_input_fn("train"), max_steps=None, hooks=hook)
eval_spec = tf.estimator.EvalSpec(input_fn=my_input_fn("valid"), steps=None)
tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(model2, train_spec, eval_spec)
```

The first trains OK but the second trains for only 1 step:

...

INFO:tensorflow:Saving dict for global step 1: LogLoss = 0.06514542, PR_AUC = 0.012231247, ROC_AUC = 0.52047175, global_step = 1, label/mean = 0.011529858, loss = 0.06514542, prediction/mean = 0.016156415

...

INFO:tensorflow:Loss for final step: 0.32117385.

I tried to run two models sequentially on the same dataset using tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate.
I expect both of the trainings run similarly. However, the second training runs for only 1 step and finishes.

Solution:
I was using tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn ([https://docs.w3cub.com/tensorflow~1.15/estimator/inputs/numpy_input_fn](https://docs.w3cub.com/tensorflow%7E1.15/estimator/inputs/numpy_input_fn)) in the second train_spec input_fn and when num_epochs=1 or not used as an argument, it terminates early. I changed to num_epochs=None and the early termination issue is solved. For this solution, max_steps=None should be set in the second training and stopping hook should be used. Additionally, early stopping hook should not be used in the second training in my case. However, this forces second training to continue for the specified number of epochs.

Comment: max_steps is fixed before training so that the training will continue for num_epochs*size of data steps. Then, if you have early stopping hook, the first training can end earlier. However, the second only runs for 1 step.

Comment: "max_steps is fixed before training" you set it to None. I don't know what that fixes it at. Does it mean it just goes as long as possible?

Comment: I set it to None on the second training and use a hook to stop training (it continues until the hook) because Tensorflow ends early if max_steps=max_steps on the second training (https://groups.google.com/a/tensorflow.org/g/discuss/c/7aAuXHbwTfU).

Comment: "it continues until the hook" isn't that what the post is about? I thought it was only doing one step?

Comment: It is supposed to run for max_steps with the hook but finished after 1 step. Models are different for the two trainings therefore max_steps in the first should not affect the second but I'll try. The code is built using the estimator.

Comment: I tried and it did not prevent stopping at step 1 on second training.

Comment: I am obtaining initial predictions from the first model and then updating the training set labels and then train the second model. The first model trains fine but the second model's input_fn terminated early. I fixed that. The code is too big to present an example.

Comment: Everything you point to uses Tensorflow 1. This isn't a good question as it stands. Maybe you can fix it by saying what your dataset is, and then you can show how to solve it. It could be a useful answer, but in the current state it is just some debugging.

Comment: tf.estimator is also used in Tensorflow 2. The solution sets num_epochs=None in numpy_input_fn. Debugging and solving problems also provides useful information.

Comment: But not to anybody else because you do not include the debugging information. You should just show how you're creating your my_input with the parameter.

Comment: Also, https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator it is deprecated which means it will be removed.

Comment: my_input_fn is a very complicated function calling 4 level deeper functions and that's why I did not include the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: I was using tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn ([https://docs.w3cub.com/tensorflow~1.15/estimator/inputs/numpy_input_fn](https://docs.w3cub.com/tensorflow%7E1.15/estimator/inputs/numpy_input_fn)) in the second train_spec input_fn and when num_epochs=1 or not used as an argument, it terminates early. So, in the solution, three things should be done:

1. I changed to num_epochs=None in numpy_input_fn and the early termination issue is solved.
2. For this solution, max_steps=None should be set in the second training and stopping hook should be used.
3. Additionally, early stopping hook should not be used in the second training in my case. However, this forces second training to continue for the specified number of epochs.

Comment: So the problem was in part of the code you didn't provide.

Comment: Yes, I did not provide the input_fn. But the solution information is helpful.